# Issue with "add-migration initial" command in Package Manager Console

Tags: .net, .net-core

I'm encountering an error, as shown in the screenshot, when I run the "add-migration initial" command in the Package Manager Console in the following project.
https://github.com/BKarayilmaz/NLayerLearningApp

**Error**

Cannot use table 'Products' for entity type 'ProductFeature' since it is being used for entity type 'Product' and potentially other entity types, but there is no linking relationship. Add a foreign key to 'ProductFeature' on the primary key properties and pointing to the primary key on another entity type mapped to 'Products'.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B96f5.png)

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you're simply "reusing" the Products table.

I would guess this should be "ProductFeatures" instead:
[image]